# Downloading image from PHP, it contains bunch of html & css code instead of the image

Tags: php, html, css

Using PHP, I'm trying to download file from this link:

http://creator.zoho.com/DownloadFile.do?filepath=/1472044441814_Lighthouse.jpg&sharedBy=29184456.

I've tried everything like `copy()`, `file_put_contents("img.jpeg",file_get_contents($url))`, curl but none work.

What's happening is that they create a image file in my server but when I view it, it shows me all the html and css and stuff like this, when I view it on window previewer it says that it can preview the picture etc etc.

Can someone please what I'm doing wrong here. Thank you.

Comment: That link redirects to a login form. If it doesn't for you, try logging off first.

Answer (score 1):

The site probably intentionally tries to make it as hard as possible.

Actually, there are 2 main ways to check this:

1. Checking the session ids, and allowing the image download only from logged in sessions of users allowed to see that picture,
2. Checking http referer.

The second is much more common.

Improve your http request to contain a valid, logged in session id and the referer what a real browser would provide. You can do this by checking the cookies and http request parameters of a regular browser. You can do very easily, for example, with the Firebug extension of the Firefox.